# windowSoftInputMode doesn't working

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode

I added the windowSoftInputMode in my AndroidManifest but it doesn't work. I tried put adjustPan, adjustResize, but nothing work.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.evehx.evehx.view.CreateAgendamentosActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

**activity_create_agendamentos.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:background="@color/bg_main"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".view.CreateAgendamentosActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/lbl_titleAgendamento"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_width="338dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioProtensao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.79"
        android:buttonTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
        android:text="@string/opt_Protensao"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioLocacao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:buttonTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
        android:text="@string/opt_Locacao"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="338dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioGroup2">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioEntrega"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:buttonTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
        android:text="@string/opt_Entrega"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioRetirada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:buttonTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
        android:text="@string/opt_Retirada"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RadioGroup>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/cmbObras"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/cmbPavimento"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cmbObras"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtDataAgendamento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cmbPavimento"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/dataEntregaRetirada"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/input_register"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar"
    android:onClick="setDate"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtDataAgendamento"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtVersaoProjeto"
    android:layout_width="357dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/ultimaVersaoProjeto"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDataAgendamento"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtDetalhesAgendamento"
    android:layout_width="352dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/btnNovoAgendamentos"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtVersaoProjeto"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/detalhes"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="12"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNovoAgendamentos"
    android:layout_width="352dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@color/btn_default_bg"
    android:text="@string/btn_send"
    android:textColor="@color/btn_default"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

When i touch on the last edit text, only the button float whit the keyboard.

[Result on edit text touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6pIe.png)

**How can i do for the edittext's move up together with the button?**

---

I solved the problem putting a scroll view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@color/bg_main">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/lbl_titleAgendamento"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioProtensao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.79"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
            android:text="@string/opt_Protensao"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioLocacao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
            android:text="@string/opt_Locacao"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioEntrega"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
            android:text="@string/opt_Entrega"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioRetirada"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center|start"
            android:text="@string/opt_Retirada"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cmbObras"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cmbPavimento"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cmbObras"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtDataAgendamento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/dataEntregaRetirada"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtDataAgendamento"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar"
            android:onClick="setDate"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtVersaoProjeto"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDataAgendamento"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/ultimaVersaoProjeto"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDetalhesAgendamento"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtVersaoProjeto"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/detalhes"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="12"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNovoAgendamentos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_default_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_send"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_default"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working as expected.  The button is bound to parentBottom, but not to anything else.  That means if the screen resizes, it will float above all other content.  If you want to make it stay below, you need to add an android:layout_below to the lowest piece of content in your screen.

Comment: Hmm, I understood! What I need to do for all elements move up together?